# How to simulate a movement in my HMI (TP700 Comfort)

Tags: siemens

Hello I'm new here so sorry about that. I have a project where I have to write a program for a car wash with Siemens TIA V16. I want to visually simulate this program with my HMI (TP700 Comfort). Whats the best way to convert my vars so that i can simulate it. The blue bar is my door, the white one is for my washing system and the grey for my fan. I want them to move like the would physically.[Simulation of the car wash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZgW9.png)

Comment: Do you mean that you want to show movement on screen similar to what is happening physically?  If yes, please update the question to reflect that

Comment: yes how do I simulate that?

Answer (score 0):

In your PLC, create tags to define the dynamic position of the objects:
[image]

In the HMI, add Movement animations to objects as required.  For Tag Name, specify the tags you created above:
[image]

I do not discuss here how to add PLC tags to the HMI.  But you can in fact browse to the PLC tag in the Tag Name field, and the software will do the rest for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The only difficulty is to write a code where I define my bool output to an INT so that I can move my object.

Comment: If the logic behind the movements is boolean, you can have two graphics on screen, and use visibility animations to show and hide them based on the status of the bool tags.